# Conditional SELECT in MySQL with Knex

Tags: knex.js

Is there a way to add IF statements to SELECT queries using Kenx? Let's say that I want to implement the following query:

```
SELECT id, name, IF(grade<60,'Fail','Pass') AS examResult FROM students;
```

Is there a way I could do something like that with Knex without using raw?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is any way of creating such a select statement with using `knex.raw`.

Your query could look like this:

```
knex.select('id', 'name', knex.raw('IF(grade<60,'Fail','Pass') AS examResult')).from('students')
```

May I ask why you don't want to use `knex.raw`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually posted that question so long ago I kinda forgot about it. Anyway, the reason I didn't want to use knex.raw was because of my misunderstanding of how raw works, which lead me to believe that I cannot combine knex.raw with other select calls, so I thought I either must use only raw or not at all. I now know that I can make combinations like you did in your short code snippet, so I already have the answer. I just forgot to close the topic.